# Is defragmentation a kind of minification, a kind of compression or perhaps both?

Tags: data-compression

As far as I understand defragmentation:

1. Removes spaces between objects by putting objects nearer one to the other
2. reorganizes objects for better performance

The first action feels to me as some kind of minification and the second action feels to me as some kind of compression.

Comment: It really depends on how you define "compression" and "minification". I suppose if you view the entire disk as a data structure, it is compression, even though it's mostly done to reduce typical access times, not for the few bytes of space it saves in disk metadata structures. "Minification" seems to me just a form of compression that is allowed to change the data, but not some more abstract property of it (it's behaviour when run as a program).

Comment: Generally in computer science we worry more about the technical and engineering and theoretical properties of an approach, and worry less about exactly which words to use to describe it.  The latter seems subjective and a matter of English language rather than science.